# Parse a xml file in Visual basic

Tags: vb.net, readxml

which is the best way to parse this xml ???

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DOCWARE Version="1.1">
<Order Count="2">
<Pos0>
   <M_TEXTNR>sAuspuffendrohr</M_TEXTNR>
   <VM_BESTNR>s02010000373</VM_BESTNR>    
   <P_PREIS>s715.80</P_PREIS>
</Pos0>
<Pos1>
   <M_TEXTNR>sMutter</M_TEXTNR>      
   <VM_BESTNR>s02010000373</VM_BESTNR>
   <P_PREIS>s0.70</P_PREIS>
</Pos1>
</Order>
<TotalSum>s</TotalSum>
</DOCWARE>
```

I Try to do so, but is not working then i = 1

```
Dim xmldoc As New XmlDataDocument()
Dim xmlnode As XmlNodeList
Dim fs As New FileStream(myFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
xmldoc.Load(fs)
For i As Integer = 0 To 1
  xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("Pos" & i)
  dim val as string = xmlnode(i).ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim()
  MsgBox(val)
Next
```

thanks in advance

Comment: *is not working then* is not a useful problem description. Code that contains `To (value from the order count) - 1)` is not actual code that we can debug. If you want help here, **clearly explain the problem, post the *actual code* you've tried, and ask a specific question**.

Comment: this is a cosmetic problem, for it is not negative vote, but you are cleverer, you know better

Comment: What is the error message, and on which line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read a tag with a changed name you can to do using xmlReader and find if you document.Name contains this prefix "Pos", try to use this code:

```
Dim document As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader(fileName)
While (document.Read())
    Dim type = document.NodeType
    If (type = XmlNodeType.Element) Then
      If (document.Name.Contains("Pos")) Then
        Dim test As String = document.ReadInnerXml.ToString()
        Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
        doc.LoadXml("<Pos>" & test & "</Pos>")
        Dim root As XmlNode = doc.FirstChild
        If root.HasChildNodes Then
            dim _value = root.ChildNodes.Item(0).InnerText.Trim()              
        End If
      End If
    End If
End While
```